# Format output of string in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparator

I have a function which accepts a string of comma separated items like for example "a, b, c, d".

I need to convert this into: "a" || "b" || "c" || "d"
Please note that the number of items in the comma separated string can be dynamic, so there can be 1, 2, 20 and so on.

Here is a sample i was trying:

```
function sample (params) {
var comp = "",
    i,
    paramsArr = params.split(","),
    status;

for (i = 0; i < paramsArr.length; i++) {
    comp += paramsArr[i] + ' ||';
}

comp = comp.substring(0, comp.length - 3);
status = comp ? "AVAILABLE" : "UNAVAILABLE";

return status;
}
```

The issue I have is that in the for loop, when i'm going though the items in the array and adding the OR operator, it obviously ends up in 1 string like "a || b || c || d" and it always evaluates to true.

Can someone please tell me how I can have the value of comp in the IF statement to be in the format "a" || "b" || "c" ?

P.S I am new to javascript, so if this not the way to go, I would be glad if you can suggest how I can achieve what I need please.

Comment: What about `"a, b, c, d".split(',').join(' || ')` ?

Comment: In reference to @Alexander's comment, see [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for usage information...

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Are you trying to build a string, or evaluate the parameters?

Comment: @ergonaut  I am trying to evaluate the parameters.  So basically I get a string with a comma separated params, and then I need to evaluate them and if the answer is truthy I show AVAILABLE label, otherwise UNAVAILABLE

Comment: If you're trying to evaluate the parameters, the title of your question is COMPLETELY misleading, or you switch/baited us.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use eval on the parms:

```
function sample (params) {
 var paramsArr = params.split(",");
 for (i = 0; i < paramsArr.length; i++) {
    if (eval(paramsArr[i])){
        return "AVAILABLE";
    } 
 }  

 return "UNAVAILABLE";
}

a=true;
b=false;
c=false;
> sample("a,b,c")
< AVAILABLE = $1
> a=false
< false = $2
> sample("a,b,c")
< UNAVAILABLE = $2
```

Comment: @ergonaut this still gives me a string, most probably it's cos im trimming the last 3 characters further down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer from Alexander.

```
"a, b, c, d".split(',').map(function(value){
  return '"' + value.trim() + '"';
}).join(' || ')
```

**output:** "a" || "b" || "c" || "d"

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8hzbcado/1/)

Comment: The demo link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

here's another possible solution:

```js
var str = "a, b, c, d";

var res = str.split(',').map(function(x) {
  return '"' + x.replace(/ /g, '') + '"'
}).join('||');

console.log(res)
```